# PDB content in a Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

I am having a project where I am having cpp, h, ini, dll and lib files / dependencies.

What is included at the end in the PDB file generated by Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you mean the pdb-file? That contains debug information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database

Comment: @MelMed Do you mean 'at the end' of the file, like the last line, or, 'at the end' as the final result of the PDB file generation?